# Unable to published workflows to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer-workflow, pause

I am using SPD 2013 and creates workflow on flatform type "SP 2010 WF".

However, checking for error it does not show any however when publishing...it gives me below error.  Can you help me identify the issue, whether it's the workflow or anything?

[image]

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In case, you are facing this issue for all workflow,**

the issue may be related to a **new .Net security update installed** and you would need to explicitly reregister the necessary types to all web applications' web.config files to solve this issue.

- Locate the web.config of your web application.
- ake a backup from this file.
- Open Web application web.config.
- Add the below lines specifically below `<System.Workflow.ComponentModel.WorkflowCompiler>` `<authorizedTypes>`

**Web Config Entries**

```
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeBinaryOperatorExpression" Authorized="True" />

<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodePrimitiveExpression" Authorized="True" />

<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeMethodInvokeExpression" Authorized="True" />

<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeMethodReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />

<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeFieldReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />

<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeThisReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />

<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodePropertyReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />
```

Check the details at [SharePoint workflows stop working after you install .NET security updates for CVE-2018-8421](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4465015/sharepoint-workflows-stop-after-cve-2018-8421-security-update)

---

**In case, you are only facing this issue for specific workflow**

Although you may have some errors in your workflow, in some wired cases, when you click on the "**Check for Errors**" button, you don't get any RED ALERT for these errors! `I think it's a bug in the SharePoint designer!`

To overcome this behavior and to make sure that you didn't have any errors in your workflow,

**Try to do the following:**

1. Save your workflow, Close it as well as close the SharePoint designer!.
2. Open it again, and click on `"Check for Errors`, so if you have errors it will be shown in Red color,
3. Try to solve these errors before performing publish!

> If you didn't get any error and still you are facing the same issue, try
>   to clear the [SharePoint designer cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113666/how-to-clear-cache-in-sharepoint-designer-site).

Check also [The workflow contains errors, but they are not visible in the current view](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/22/the-workflow-contains-errors-but-they-are-not-visible-in-the-current-view/)

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this issue multiple times while I was updating workflows. If you copy and paste some part of the code, you will get this type of errors.

My recommendation is to clear the cache and try to publish it again. if it fails again, try to remove line by line and re-write the code line by line and keep publishing the code to figure out where the issue is. Based on you attached screenshot, first I review the conditions and rewrite them and make sure the values are selected correctly.

Unfortunately, there is no easy/better way of debugging SharePoint workflows by using SharePoint Designer.